# Extending a union type from an extended interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

If I have this interface definition:

```
interface ModalProps {
    onClose: (event: {}, reason: 'backdropClick' | 'escapeKeyDown'): void;
}
```

Now I want to add an additional reason:

```
interface CustomModalProps {
    onClose: (event: {}, reason: 'backdropClick' | 'escapeKeyDown' | 'cancelClick'): void;
}
```

Is there any way I can reference the ModalProps onClose reason from within CustomModalProps, so that I don't have to copy the values?

```
interface CustomModalProps extends ModalProps {
  onClose: (event: {}, reason: ??? &| 'cancelClick'): void
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Us types.

```
type ModalReason = 'backdropClick' | 'escapeKeyDown';

type CustomModaReason = ModalReason | 'cancelClick';

interface ModalProps {
    onClose: (event: {}, reason: ModalReason): void;
}

interface CustomModalProps {
    onClose: (event: {}, reason: CustomModaReason): void;
}
```